# ngx-mercadopago

Tags: mercadopago

estoy implementando ngx-mercadoPago en Angular basandome en la documentación que ofrece
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mercadopago y https://github.com/gabfiocchi/ngx-mercadopago, pero al momento de crear el servicio me da el siguiente error

Argumento de tipo 'Cadena | undefined 'no se puede asignar a un parámetro de tipo' cadena '.
El tipo 'indefinido' no se puede asignar al tipo 'cadena'

```
/** @hidden */
const pathSDK = environment.SDKMercadoPago;
/** @hidden */
export const ConfigToken = new InjectionToken<NgxMercadopagoConfiguration>(environment.accessToken);

declare var Mercadopago: MercadopagoSDk;
export class NgxMercadopagoService {
  initialized: boolean;
  constructor(
    private config: NgxMercadopagoConfiguration,
  ) {
    if (!config.pathSDK) {
      config.pathSDK = pathSDK;
    }

    this.initialized = false;
  }
initialize(publishKey?: string): Promise<MercadopagoSDk> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sdkMercadoPago = this.loadMPScript(**this.config.pathSDK**)<--aqui!;

      sdkMercadoPago.onload = () => {
        this.initialized = true;
        Mercadopago.setPublishableKey(publishKey || this.config.publishKey);

        return resolve(Mercadopago);
      };
      sdkMercadoPago.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
  }

  loadMPScript(src: string): HTMLScriptElement {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return script;
  }
```

Si tienen algun tutorial y/o manual de como implementar ngx-mercadopago en Angular me ayudaria mucho

Comment: En que linea te arroja ese error.

Comment: const sdkMercadoPago = this.loadMPScript(**this.config.pathSDK**)<--aqui!;

Comment: el error que te indica es que la función loadMPScript, recibe un string y tu le estas pasando un valor undefined, revisa que tu variable `this.config.pathSDK` lleve un valor,  por que validas si no tiene y le asignas el de `enviroment.SDKMercadoPago` y supongo ahí es donde te asigna el undefined

Comment: ¡Gracias Eduardo!, tienes algún tutorial de como implementar mercadoPago y/o consumir su api